# How do I change a specific value found when looping a 2d array?

Tags: javascript

Trying to replace values of an array in an array.
The array only has values 1 or 0, it is a grid.
Code is looking for a 1 and change that to 0 and also change the same column value of the row below to 1.

I belive the problem is im making the if statement invalid with the changes im trying to make. Resulting in error message.

```
function gravity() {
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      if (grid[i][j] === 1){
        grid[i][j] = 0;
        grid[i+1][j] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What error message?

Comment: Keep in mind if you are on the last row, trying to access i + 1 will go out of bounds of the array, returning an undefined before you try to do the `[j]`.

Comment: Thanks Taplar you are right, also rows needed to be looped in reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when your loop is in the last row it will try to set `i+1` to `1`, but since `i` is already the last index `i+1` is out of bounds.

To fix this you can simply add an `if`

You also have another bug. Since you interate from top to bottom you move any 1's down to the next row, then you go through the next row and find the exact same 1's that you have just moved down and move them down again. This repeats until all 1's are gone, all in a single call to gravity(). To fix this you have to interate through the rows from bottom to top.

```js
var grid = [
  [1,0,0,0],
  [0,0,1,0],
  [0,0,0,0],
  [0,1,0,0]
]

var cols = 4;
var rows = 4;

function gravity() {
  for (var i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      if (grid[i][j] === 1){
        grid[i][j] = 0;
        if(i+1 < rows) {
          grid[i+1][j] = 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var iterations = 0;

var intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  gravity();
  for(var row of grid) {
    console.log(row.join(','))
  }
  console.log("");
  iterations++;
  if(iterations == 4) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}, 400)
```

Comment: That works. Out of bounds, ohh you mean when I hit the last row I will be trying to change the value in a row that doesn't exist. Now I see.  Thanks.

Comment: Thats awsome, I was trying to figgure out why it seemd to work but not quite as I expected. Thank's again.